# CSS: Exchange 2 elements position

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have 2 elements created by a library so I can not change the order in the html itself:

```
<div class="search-container">
  <div class="tags"></div>
  <input class="search"/>
</div>
<div class="my-list">
...
</div>
```

I need to place input above the div. I have moved input above using position absolute:

```
.search-container {
  position: relative;
}

.search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.tags {
  position: relative;
  top: 38px;
}
```

But I got some issues:

- .search-container height is not correct.
- .search-container does not grow as more tags are added

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be able to do it with `flex`. Flex has an `order` property.

Comment: @mhatch it worked!!, please add it as answer to select it

Comment: Eduardo, you can also post and accept your own answer, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @mhatch comment on my question. I implemented following solution:

```
.search-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.search {
  order: 1;
}

.tags {
  order: 20;
}
```

Comment: you may also use flex-direction: row-reverse | column-reverse